# vim script for editing gvimrc, if else statement

Tags: if-statement, vim

I am new to the vim scripting.
I wants to know how can I use the "if else" statement to the below situation.

In my .gvimrc I have set the background as *dark* and it can be change to *light* also

```
set background dark
```

Now I am planning to change the marginal color (*LineNr*) depends on the *background* selection like below

```
if background == dark
   highlight LineNr guibg=Black guifg=Yellow
else
  highlight LineNr guibg=White guifg=Blue
endif
```

The above statement is wrong. Please let me know how can I write the **if** statement for the above case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
if &background == "dark"
```